# SSIS: How to keep package TFS version history when copying package into a new package by using copy-paste method in Visual Studio?

Tags: tfs, ssis, version-control

I would like to copy/paste an SSIS package named "A" and thus create a new package named "B". Is there a way that package "B" can inherit TFS version history that package "A" has in TFS Catalog at that moment? Thank you, Milan

EDITED:

SSIS Package_A has this history of versions saved in TFS Catalog: (see image below)

[Version history of Package_A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KiR1.png)

When I copy-paste-rename Package_A into new Package_B, that new package has this versions history:

[Version history of package_B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFL3.png)

Is there a way that when I create new Package_B by copy-paste from Package_A, that the new Package_B can have the same history that is visible for Package_A, the same 5 versions records visible in front of the new version of Package_B ?

Comment: What does "keep TFS version history" specifically refer to? Can you give a screenshot to indicate it? Besides, here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/copy-a-package-in-sql-server-data-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) you can refer to.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.